# Displaying line breaks in XML using ASP.NET with XSLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, line-breaks

I have a problem with my XML that I am trying to display on my ASP.NET page that I could do with some help with.
What I would like to do is display it on a multi-line so I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="News.xslt" ?>
<newslist>
  <news>
    <date>20th June 2010</date>
    <detail>Detail line 1.
            Detail Line 2</detail>
  </news>
  <news>
    <date>18th June 2010</date>
    <detail>Some more details</detail>
  </news>
</newslist>
```

And I have an XSLT file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="newslist/news">
          <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending"/>
          <br />
          <h3><xsl:value-of select="date" /></h3>
          <ul>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="detail" /></p>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When it displays the first detail line everything is on the same line.  I've done some digging about and I have tried the following:

1. xml:space="preserve" in the XSLT file
2. in the XML file
3. `<br />`
4. I've even tried leaving it as it is.

I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010.  The control I am using is the XML control under the standard tab, and the language I am using is C#, if that helps any.

If this has already been answered and I haven't found it yet can you please point me at it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you add the <br/> to the XML source file or to the XSLT file? You should be able to put hte <br/> into your XML source file without any problems.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="newslist/news">
          <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending"/>
          <br />
          <h3><xsl:value-of select="date" /></h3>
          <ul>
            <p><xsl:apply-templates select="detail"/></p>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="detail/text()" name="textLines">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '&#xA;')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
          <br />
          <xsl:call-template name="textLines">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
             "substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"
             />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$pText"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<newslist>
  <news>
    <date>20th June 2010</date>
    <detail>Detail line 1.
            Detail Line 2</detail>
  </news>
  <news>
    <date>18th June 2010</date>
    <detail>Some more details</detail>
  </news>
</newslist>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY><br><h3>20th June 2010</h3>
        <ul>
            <p>Detail line 1.<br>            Detail Line 2</p>
        </ul><br><h3>18th June 2010</h3>
        <ul>
            <p>Some more details</p>
        </ul>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```